# Testing a Rest Web Service in salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce

I am developing a Rest Web service in salesforce.com platform. I wrote it and it is working properly and giving accurate responses when I call it. The problem is how to test it

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/feedpost/*')

    global class Feedpost9
    {
      @HttpPut
      global static User updateCase() {
         RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
         User user=[SELECT id from User where email=:req.headers.get('email') LIMIT 1];
         return user;          
    }

}
```

Now my task is to test this REST web service method `updateCase`. For testing a POST request method I have to set the parameters in method call but in case of PUT method - how do I set `RestContext.request` in the test class?

Comment: Salesforce stack exchange is a great place for questions like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues you must contend with in your unit tests:

- The need for a valid RestRequest
- The lack of data in a test environment

Here is basic technique to setting up the request object your method wants

```
global class Feedpost9 {

    // your methods here...

    static testMethod void testRest() {
        // set up the request object
        System.RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
        RestContext.request.requestURI = '/feedpost/whatever';
        RestContext.request.addHeader('email', 'blahblah@some.org');
        // Invoke the method directly
        Feedpost9.updateCase();
    }
}
```

The other problem you're likely to have is that in Salesforce v24 and above unit-tests, by default, do not have access to your data.  That's because unit tests run in a kind of sandbox that have none of your data, but *do* contain your metadata (RecordTypes, etc).  So, there are two techniques for getting data to your tests:

1. Use the `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` annotation on your method.  This will give the test method access to your data.
2. Have your test method build/insert the test data, then run your tests against that data.  When the testing ends, your test data will miraculously disappear from your database.

I prefer to use the later method, but sometimes I cheat...

Comment: If you're planning to distribute this code (eg as a managed package), I'd strongly advice creating your own test data. You can't be sure if the organization that has your code has the test data you need already.

Comment: Using existing data for testing is a lazy fix that's bound to bite you in the future. If you don't have time to properly create the test data, fix your development process.
Only good reason I know to use SeeAllData is for data validation tests.